# Twitter iOS App v5.3 UINavigationController Back Button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter, sdk

In the recently released update to the Twitter app, the text was removed from the back button and replaced with an arrow. It looks really nice and simple, but I can't work out how they did it.

[image: New Twitter Back Button]

I tried playing around with the iOS 5 UI customisation, but nothing really worked well. I can get it to work if I set the leftBarButtonItem, but that means I would have to do it in each view controller and write my own action to pop the view controller. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a custom navigation bar and button item.Add this code:

```
 UINavigationBar * bar =[[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:bar];

//Back Button
UIButton *btnback = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnback setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 7, 54, 29)];
[btnback setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//UILabel * btnlabel =  [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 40, 23)];
//btnlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//btnlabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//btnlabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
//btnlabel.text = @"back";
//[btnback addSubview:btnlabel];
//[btnlabel release];
//btnlabel = nil;
[btnback addTarget:self action:@selector(BackAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[bar addSubview:btnback];
[bar release];
```

Answer (score 0):

No need set backButton or add it as subView of navigationController. You only need to set back button attribute in mainViewController. like

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

buttonBack32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 4)];

buttonBack24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 4)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack32 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack24 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
self.navigationItem.backButton = backButton;
```

Or you cane follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5